# Extracting text from Tkinter in python is printing none

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want that to print value that one enters in input box gets printed, and later I'll use it with SQL, but when I run this, it prints with None in terminal.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window=Tk()

def submit():
    label.config(text=""+text.get(1.0, "end-1c"))
    pri = label.config(text=""+text.get(1.0, "end-1c"))
    print(str(pri))



# Add a text widget
text=Text(window, width=80, height=15)
text.insert(END, "")
text.pack()

# Create a button to get the text input
b=ttk.Button(window, text="Print", command=submit)
b.pack()

# Create a Label widget
label=Label(window, text="", font=('Calibri 15'))
label.pack()




window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You print out the result of `label.config(...)` which is always None.  I think you want to print out `text.get(1.0, "end-1c")` or `label['text']` instead. Also you have executed `label.config(...)` twice.

Answer (score 0):

> but when I run this, it prints with None in terminal.

That is not the way you write  in `submit` function.

Correct way:

```
def submit():    
    pri = text.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    label.config(text=pri)
    print(pri)
```

Screenshot:

[image]